# Prove that $\dot{x}={f(t)\over g(x+t)}-1$ can be solved by separation of variables.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that $\dot{x}={f(t)\over g(x+t)}-1$ can be solved by separation of variables. (All functions here are continuously differentiable and continuous in particular).
I really need help regarding what to do and regarding the suggestion that I already have:

$g(x+t):=h(t)$, $\dot x+1={f(t)\over g(x+t)}$ $h'(t)=g'(x+t)(\dot x+1)={g'(x+t)}{f(t)\over h(t)}$  Then everything got messy and complex algebraically to the point I actually forgot what exactly I am supposed to show. I would appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation:

I am not sure why you need the suggestion.  Rewrite the ODE as $$\dot{x}+1 = \frac{f(t)}{g(x+t)}$$ and make the substitution $y(t) = x(t)+t$.  We then get that $\dot{y} = \dot{x} + 1 = \frac{f(t)}{g(y)}$.  So then $\dot{y} = \frac{f(t)}{g(y)}$ which can then easily be solved by separation of variables.  We then get the solution $x(t) = y(t)-t$.

I guess, technically, we are not solving the ODE directly by separation of variables, but the substitution makes it possible.

Comment: This is what I sort of did in my attempt but I still don't manage to see how it is solvable so directly.

Comment: I guess I am not sure that it always is separable without the substitution.  Consider the case where f(s) = g(s) = s.  Then the ODE takes the form $\dot{x} = \frac{t}{x+t} - 1 = \frac{-x}{x+t}$.  I don't see how you could separate the variables in this case.

Comment: It is basically first exercise. I guess we are not required to do so much in one question. What you did at first seemed really cathartic but with that doubt now I don't know what to do.

Comment: I will offer bounty, and maybe your comment will be referred to and I will understand whether or not and why, it is true or not. Thank you so far for helping :)
If you arrive at something new, I'd appreciate it if you updated me.

Comment: @Meitar: There is nothing complicated here: the equation can be rewritten as $g(y) \dot y = f(t)$, which can be immediately integrated: $\int g(y(t)) \dot y (t) \Bbb d t = \int f(t) \Bbb d t$, or $G(y(t)) = F(t) + C$, where $G$ is the antiderivative of $g$, $F$ the antiderivative of $f$ and $C$ an integration constant. If $G$ is invertible you get $y(t) = G^{-1} (F(t) + C)$, so $x(t) = G^{-1} (F(t) + C) - t$.

Comment: Is it possible that $G(y)=0.5(g(y))^2$?